# Cannot print System Local Time with use Time::localtime function in Perl

Tags: perl, time

I have written a Perl script to obtain specific information from config files

```
use Time::localtime;
my $date_string = ctime(stat($filepath)->mtime);
print "$date_string\t";
```

the above code prints the last modified time and date of the file, but the problem is I could not print the report generation time with the following function

```
my $time = localtime; # scalar context
print "executed successfully at $time\n";
```

I get the following error

```
executed successfully at Time::tm=ARRAY(0x336e048)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Time::localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/localtime.html) module default exports override the core localtime() function, replacing it with a version that returns "Time::tm" objects

So if you want to use the core Perl localtime, write this way:

```
my $time = CORE::localtime;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you get the reference to an array. So the reference is printed.

use

```
my $time = scalar(CORE::localtime); # scalar context
```

more Information to the `scalar`function you can find [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_scalar.htm)

> Description
>   This function forces the evaluation of EXPR to be in
>   scalar context, even if it would normally work in list context.
>
> Syntax
>     Following is the simple syntax for this function:  scalar
>   EXPR  Return Value
>     This function returns Scalar

Comment: even now I get the error
`Time::tm=ARRAY(0x359eb70)`

Comment: Thanks Jens, is there any specific advantage of using 
`scalar(CORE::localtime)` instead of just `CORE::localtime`

Comment: Yes `CORE::LOcation gives you a reference to an array, so if you only print the result, you print the reference of the array. `scalar`gives you the scalar context, so you get the string.

Comment: No, an explicit call to [`scalar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) is **redundant** here.  The [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) will automatically detect if it is used in a scalar or list context.  By assigning it to $time, it is automatically interpreted in a scalar context.